# Regular expression to find string after a specific word pattern

Tags: regex, dataweave

How do I fetch a string using Regex after matching with specific word pattern? For example, here is my sample string

```
some html code </p>\n\n<p> </p>\n\n<p><img alt=\"\" height=\"397\" src=\"https://actual-image-url\" width=\"537\"></img> </p>\n\n<p><br> <br>some html code
```

Here I wanted to find imgage source url, which means give me the src= value within the <img tag. So my desired string is "https://actual-image-url"

Appreciate any answers, thanks.

I tried it with:

```
/<img\s.*\Ksrc=\\"\K.*\\"\s
```

It worked with some online tool. But my software (Dataweave) didn't like it, it threw error for `\K` as unsupported char.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See the 
[How to Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question. Include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to 
reproduce the issue. See also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [I might suggest finding another way besides regex to parse your HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to use regex features from some other implementation that may not be supported by DataWeave.

Assuming that you want it for your exact input, which includes extra escapes of quotes:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload scan(/<img[^>]*src=\"([^"]+)/)) map $[1]
```

Note that match() needs to match the entire input string, and index 0 is the full string. Using the range selector to return items with index 1 and greater returns the source URL.

Output (for your exact input):

```json
[
  "https://actual-image-url\\"
]
```

Comment: for some reason it did not work with match() function but the following Regex worked with scan() function.
scan(/<img [^>]*src=\“([^“]+)/)
I still wonder why it is not working with match() function

Comment: Are you using the exact input from the question? What's the data type?

Comment: It probably has to do with the escaping in the input format. I updated my answer to use scan() and also to support multiple `img` tags in the input.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following *capture pattern*.

The value will be in capture-group 2.

```
<img\s.+?src=.*?(['\"])(.*?)\\\1
```

- `<img\s`, match the *img* start tag
- `.+?src=`, match all characters up to *"src="*
- `.*?(['\"])`, match any characters up to, and capturing, a `'` or `"`
- `(.*?)\\\1`, capture any characters up a matching `'` or `"`.

Answer (score 0):

the following code worked,

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.message scan(/<img [^>]*src=\"([^"]+)/) map $[-1]
```